# Extensions of a cyclic group by a cyclic group: confusion in understanding

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading a paper ([this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864111002318)), but confused at one point. The author mentions following:

> **Theore 2.5** If the action $\theta:\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow {\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ is injective then $H^s(\mathbb{Z}_n, \mathbb{Z}_m)=0$ for $s>0$. Hence, there is only one extension
> $$
> 1\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow 1.$$

**Confusion:** If we take $m=4$ and $n=2$, and if action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is taken non-trivial one, we should get two extensions - $D_8$ and $Q_8$; how the author asserts that  first, second cohomology group is trivial?

Can one help to clarify the assertion of the author?

Comment: See Proposition $2.1$ and Corollary $2.2$.

Comment: Possibly: the confusion lies in understanding of the term **injective action**. I searched this term, but got no reference of it. However, if we understand **injective action** as **fixed-point-free action**, then the assertion seems true: if $\alpha$ is fixed point free automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_m$, then order of $\alpha$ should divide $m-1$, hence order of $\alpha$ should be coprime to $m$. (With this understanding, then his hypothesis implies that $n$ is coprime to $m$.) Is this correct?

Comment: @MathsRahul That's true, but I looked at the paper, and it seemed as though the author understood injective  action to mean that $\theta$ is injective. It looks as though that result is just plain wrong, and in fact it contradicts Proposition 2.3 (1), according to which the cohomology group has order $2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Prop 2.1 and Cor. 2.2. are dealing with odd primes $p$. The case $p=2$ is done in Prop 2.3 and Cor. 2.4.